# Access main thread control in backgroundworker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a function `ShowPanel(Control ctrl)` which required to pass `Control` as parameter.
I need to call this function in background worker thread. I use following code

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
{                      
    ShowPanel(listBox1);           
}
```

But fails with execption

> *Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on*

How can I pass `listBox1` here in background thread ?

Comment: If listbox1 is created on the main UI, you need to call the function in a progresschangedevent of the backgroundworker. And you need to call the ReportProgress from the doworkevents.

Answer (score 6):

serilize the call , since you can not access a control which is created on different thread , you need to seriliaze the call using below

```
 void bw_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {                      
   this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {

              ShowPanel(listBox1);           
    })); 
 }
```

Comment: by doing this, It gives me no exception but still `ShowPanel(listBox1)` function called only after main thread complete its execution

Comment: @rajeevkumar make sure that your thread is not doing something else or waiting for something while you are r invoking the method from back ground! if it does, it will execute the UI code after completing it's task

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there should be BeginInvoke instead of Invoke.

Otherwise here's more generic solution.

You need to add a reference to WindowsBase.dll.

On the main thread get thread's dispatcher:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher mainThreadDispatcher;       

    // assuming class is instantiated in a main thread, otherwise get a dispatcher to the
    // main thread
    public SomeClass()
    {
        Dispatcher mainThreadDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    }

    public void MethodCalledFromBackgroundThread()
    {
        mainThreadDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)({() => ShowPanel(listBox1);}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Dispatcher thing works in 3.5 as well, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: but on adding reference to windowbase.dll it give me following warning `WindowBase.dll or one of its dependency required later version of .net framerwork than the one specified in the project ...`

Comment: Ok i got it working, but your syntax for ` mainThreadDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)() => ShowPanel(listBox1));` seems to be wrong. It is not compiling. Giving error invalid expression term '('. Invalid Expression term '=>'

Comment: I tried with following syntax but same result i.e ShowPanel execute only after main thread completes `mainThreadDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    ShowPanel(listBox);
                }));`

Comment: try the edited version. I probably missed some parenthesis, don't have Windows machine around to check whether this compiles

Comment: And if your main thread is doing something else (like waiting for a semaphore to be set from the background thread or some calculations) then ShowPanel will be executed only after you're done with that work, so you have to make sure there's nothing going on on your main thread.